# How to calculate summary statistics for certain consecutive day ranges

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset (DATE_LOCATION, Sold) which has products sold on various dates. The dates are being given for 9 months with random 13 days or more from a month. I have to segregate the data in a such a way that the for the product how many products were sold continuously for  1-3 days, sold continuously for 4-7 given days, sold continuously for 8-15 given days and sold continuously for>16 days. So how can I code this in python using pandas and other packages

```
      DATE_LOCATION  Sold
      07-08-16 0:00    2
      08-08-16 0:00    7
      12-08-16 0:00    3
      13-08-16 0:00    1
      14-08-16 0:00    2
      15-08-16 0.00    1
      .
      . 
      .
      22-10-16 0:00    1
      23-10-16 0:00    2
      26-10-16 0:00    1
      28-10-16 0:00    1
      29-10-16 0:00    3
      30-10-16 0:00    3
      .
      .
      .(goes for 9 months of data)
      .
```

I don't know even how to code for this in python
The output needed is

```
 Days   Sold
 1-3     20 #(7,8),(22,23),(26),(28,29,30) dates because the range is [1,3]
 4-7      7 #(12,13,14,15) dates because the range is [4,7]
 8-15     0
  >16     0
```

Would be happy if at least someone posted a link to where to start.
I tried

```
df["DATE_LOCATION"] = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE_LOCATION)
df["DAY"] = df.DATE_LOCATION.dt.day
def flag(x):
    if 1<=x<=3:
        return '1-3'
    elif 4<=x<=7:
        return '4-7'
    elif 8<=x<=15:
        return '8-15'
    else:
        return '>=16'
df["Days"] = df.DAY.apply(flag)
df["Days"].Sold.sum()
```

This gave me the number of products sold between these days in each month. But I need the sum of the products for the specified range where the products are sold in a streak specified.

Comment: that gives me the number of products sold between these days 1-3,4-7,8-15,>16 in each month. I need the need the number of products sold for the range of days continuously for 1-3 days, 4-7 days...

Comment: I don't need the number of products sold between the days     Example if the product is sold for 2 days continuously I need it to be placed in the 1-3 range and if the product is sold for next  30 days continuously I need it to be placed in >16 range. Doesn't depend on what day it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced input data by this code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_LOCATION': ['07-08-16 0:00', '08-08-16 0:00', '12-08-16 0:00',\
                                     '13-08-16 0:00', '14-08-16 0:00', '15-08-16 0:00',\
                                     '22-10-16 0:00', '23-10-16 0:00', '26-10-16 0:00',\
                                     '28-10-16 0:00', '29-10-16 0:00', '30-10-16 0:00',],\
                   'Sold': [2, 7, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3]})
df.DATE_LOCATION = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE_LOCATION, dayfirst=True)
```

Now the data looks like this

```
   DATE_LOCATION  Sold
0     2016-08-07     2
1     2016-08-08     7
2     2016-08-12     3
3     2016-08-13     1
4     2016-08-14     2
5     2016-08-15     1
6     2016-10-22     1
7     2016-10-23     2
8     2016-10-26     1
9     2016-10-28     1
10    2016-10-29     3
11    2016-10-30     3
```

Get interval between rows, calculate run length (consecutive days) and group them as far as run length continues to extend, finally get max run_length and sum of sold items in each group are summarized.

```
df['Day_Interval'] = df.DATE_LOCATION.diff().shift(0).fillna(0)

# calculate run length
day_intervals = (df.Day_Interval.values / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
run_lengths = []
run_length = 0
groups = []
group = 0

for day_interval in day_intervals:
    if day_interval != 1:
        run_length = 1
        group += 1
        groups.append(group)
    else:
        run_length += 1
        groups.append(group)
    run_lengths.append(run_length)

df['Run_Length'] = run_lengths
df['Group'] = groups

# calculate summary statistic by group
df = df.groupby('Group')['Sold', 'Run_Length'].agg({'Sold': np.sum, 'Run_Length': np.max})
df['1-3'] = 0
df['4-7'] = 0
df['8-15'] = 0
df['>=16'] = 0

df.loc[(df.Run_Length >= 1) & (df.Run_Length <=3), "1-3"] = df.Sold
df.loc[(df.Run_Length >= 4) & (df.Run_Length <=7), "4-7"] = df.Sold
df.loc[(df.Run_Length >= 8) & (df.Run_Length <=15), "8-15"] = df.Sold
df.loc[(df.Run_Length >= 16), ">=16"] = df.Sold
df = df.T.iloc[2:]
df['Sold'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df = df[['Sold']]
```

Output (`df`):

```
Group   Sold
1-3     20
4-7     7
8-15    0
>=16    0
```

Hope this helps.